# Using CoWaitForMultipleHandles

Tags: multithreading, delphi

Continuing from

[Pausing execution of a Thread WITHOUT sleeping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396174/pausing-execution-of-a-thread-without-sleeping)

How do I use the CoWaitForMultipleHandles routine, as Lars Truijens suggested? I found the routine in the SyncObjs unit, however I get "undeclared identifier" when trying to call it? The IDE Insight does not bring anything up either? And yes, I have added SyncObjs to my Uses clause.

I can't see what other info I need to include - however feel more than free to ask for more info!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call this function from SyncObjs, because it hasn't been declared in interface section. But `TEvent.WaitFor` actually calls CoWaitForMultipleHandles. Did you try it?

And please note its constructor declaration:

```
{ Specify UseCOMWait to ensure that when blocked waiting for the object
  any STA COM calls back into this thread can be made. }
constructor Create(UseCOMWait: Boolean = False);
```

Comment: I am using the TSkype COM object, how could I implement your answer?

Comment: Create an instance of TEvent _Event := TEvent.Create(**True**);_. And then call _Event.WaitFor(1000 {any timeout value})_ to wait. If success return value will be _wrSignaled_.

Comment: So that will allow my TSkype to "finish chewing"?

Comment: You should try :). I did't work with TSkype COM, I just tell you how to use CoWaitForMultipleHandles via TEvent in Delphi.

Comment: reason I ask now is because I have no compiler at hand, and if it would not work, perhaps I would have another answer for when I got home. But I have a good feeling about it, will let you know :)